# Table of Contents links are not clickable on PDF export when i choose Table [Libreoffice]

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am writing my *Thesis* & i am showing some statistical tables in my *Libreoffice Writer 5.4.7.2* portable version. I have created a *Table of Contents* (TOC) for my chapters, images, tables and also source codes.

However, only chapters & images *TOC* links are clickable when i export my *.ODT* file to *.PDF* file. I still see all of my *TOC* getting created, but i cannot click tables & source codes *TOC* links on PDF export.

The exact procedure (for tables) that i am following is this:

- Create the table
- Focus on a cell
- Insert > Caption > write my text in *Caption* & choose Category as *Table*
- Right click on *TOC* for tables & click *Update Index*
- I see my updated *TOC*, however no clickable links on PDF export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

It turned out this is a [bug](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37608) in *Libreoffice Writer*, dated from 2011.

There's a workaround on this when creating the table of contents by setting the **Type** to `Illustration` and **Category** to `Table`, then export to `PDF` normally.

Then links on `PDF` works normally.